# Is it possible to get Arrival/Destination Time from Google Map App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing *ionic* application for *Android*. I want to open the **Google Map App** from my Application. Using **launchnavigator**,

```
launchnavigator.navigate([50.279306, -5.163158], {
    start: "50.342847, -4.749904"
};
```

I can able to achieve this. Can anyone clarify my following doubts,

Is it possible to get the Arrival/Destination time from google Map App????

And also Is it possible to redirect to my App again???

Anyone Help will be Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

- Is it possible to get the Arrival/Destination time from google Map App.

> Launch navigator will launch a Google Map where you can see the starting point and destination point with direction connecting between those. So you can get the Arrival and Destination time from there if You Start the Navigate in the Google Maps.
>
> FYI: if you select start point as null it will then take your current
>   location.
>
> BUT: if you want the data of of arrival time into your App its not
>   possible due to Policy restriction.

- And also Is it possible to redirect to my App again???

> I don't know Exactly but if you click the back button it will redirect you again to your Application. Cause the Google Api started from your App in the first Place.

Comment: If we click on start from google map app, Can we able to get the start time as well destination time by coding???

Comment: i think you will get the start time and destination time in the Google map application. but you cant' bring back any kind of data from the google maps. if you are interested getting time between two points use the **Google MAP API**

Comment: Using API is for opening google map not for google map App right??

Comment: If it is possible, can u tell me how get the start time and destination time from Google map application using launch navigator?? Because I surfed lot. I was not getting any solution!!!!!

Comment: Well i can't write the code and deliver to you. but i can help you where you can find the answer use this as a reference [link] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: This is another link for distance matrix [link] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)